Thunderbird: Long text doesn't wrap in bullet Lists
Hi I see an issue in different emails that contain bullet lists with long text. Actually the text doesn't wrap at all and you need to move horizontal bar or zoom out to read it. Before I write this I did a search on the Internet and here and I didn't find anything similar. Just a bug a long ago witch solved in 52 Version.
Image
So I assume I use the wrong search keys or I can fixed by changing some settings?

I used version 115.14.0 just update to 128.1.1esr but issue still
exists
My setting on View->Message body as is to Original HTLM. If I use simple HTML the text wrapped although many other things like bold
text doesn't show up.

